# Como criar um arquivo .jar apropriadamente?

Tags: java, compilação, jar

Eu, que sou totalmente novo em Java , estou tentando compilar um projeto "Hello, World!" . Eu segui algumas etapas [desse tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941296/how-do-i-make-a-jar-from-a-java) do Stack Overflow em inglês. Eu segui todos os passos, mas quando vou abrir meu jar, dá erro. Eu o abri, e ví que era culpa do manifesto. Eu procurei, mas até agora não achei nenhuma maneira de adicionar a classe principal no manifesto. O que eu devo fazer?

Comment: Olá, você pode colocar na pergunta o comando que você fez para gerar o jar? O conteúdo do manifest e a mensagem de erro também vão ajudar bastante as pessoas tentando lhe ajudar.

Comment: Hehehe, era uma pergunta de Wiki :P

Comment: Hum, talvez devesse haver uma tag para indicar essas perguntas que a própria pessoa pretende responder.

Comment: Pior que só no PT que ainda não tem `'-'`. Dá para fazer como "community wiki" no Stack Overflow em Inglês.

Comment: Essencialmente perguntas não devem ser wiki. Quase todas as situações que uma pergunta deva ser wiki, tem algo errado com ela. Não entendi o que é esse '-' que você diz que falta. @C.E.Gesser não deve ter esse tipo de tag, isso é chamado de meta-tag e não acrescenta nada à pergunta.

Comment: @bigown Tudo bem, desculpe, e '-' é a mesma coisa que ¬¬, é um "emoticon" (por exemplo - :D)

Comment: @LucasHenrique Se achar que deve, pode abrir uma pedido ou bug no meta para ter.

Comment: @bigown Hahahaha, não estou pedindo " '-' ", e sim community wiki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa é uma pergunta muito comum.
A compilação de um manifesto é externa, usando o `-m`. Nesse caso, por exemplo, os passos seriam:

1. `javac HelloWorld.java` - criar o .class
2. Criar um manifesto.mf com o seguinte conteúdo:
   `Main-Class: HelloWorld`
3. Simplesmente compilar com as tags `jar cvmf manifesto.mf arquivo_jar_desejado.jar HelloWorld.class`

*<Oracle & Sun>*

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

*<Externos>*

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767886/use-of-manifest-file-in-java

Comment: Apenas para mencionar uma alternativa; para um simples `HelloWorld` você pode deixar a ferramenta jar gerar o `MANIFEST.MF` com o ponto de entrada: `jar cfe app.jar HelloWorld HelloWorld.class` (referência: [The Java™ Tutorials - Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)). Esse método é mais prático do que gerar um Manifest na unha.