# Como gerar programa executável .jar no VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Opa, realizei uma aplicação em java, agora preciso obter o executável .jar. Como faço para obter o .jar no VS Code?

Comment: Possivel duplicata ou relacionada:[Como criar um arquivo .jar apropriadamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4879/28595)

Comment: O `VSCODE` não tem relação com a geração do `.jar`. Você está procurando uma forma automatizada, é isso?

Comment: Qual plugin você utiliza pra compilar e rodar o código Java no VS Code?

Comment: Opa, Marcelo entendi pensei que havia alguma forma, eu conheço pelo netbeans

Comment: Tanto o netbeans quanto o eclipse utilizam o [ant](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/259756/28595) para automatizar a criação dos jars, so que no netbeans, ele se encarrega de configurar o build.xml, e no eclipse nem sempre isso ocorre e as vezes é necessário configurar manualment.

Comment: Articuno - Mais no VS Code teria alguma possibilidade de obter esse executável?

Comment: LINQ - Eu não uso nenhum no momento estou querendo descobrir, eu vi que possui um plugin do Manven

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pode usar o comando:

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

Onde input-file(s) são as classes que vc quer no jar. O visual code tem um terminal embutido.

Comment: Valeu Bruno... Vou realizar esse teste aqui

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver com uma versão atualizada do Visual Studio Code você pode configurar no `task.json`.

- Primeiro é necessário criar uma "pasta de projeto", clique no botão `Add workspace`, como na imagem:

  [image: workspace]
- Pode notar que eu criei um workspace (seria como um projeto) chamado `java-teste`
- Aperte os botões do teclado Ctrl+Shift+p
- Na busca digitei "Configure Task"
- Clique no menu "Create tasks.json file from template"
- Irá aparecer algumas opções, selecione "Others"

Ele irá gerar um template padrão, como isto:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo Hello"
        }
    ]
}
```

Você poderá customizar e adicionar o `javac` pra criar os `.class` e depois o `jar cf <nome do jar>` para criar o `.jar`

---

Note que `.jar` não é um executável, mas sim um pacote, como se fosse um instalador ou algo assim, se o que deseja é apenas executar o seu script você pode instalar uma extensão, segue uma que é feita para isto:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=caolin.java-run

Comment: Valeu Guilherme. Vou realizar este teste... Desculpa a demora em retornar